# Excel if A1 cell value is equal to A2 cell value select M3 cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want a simple thing. if A1 cell value is equal to A2 cell value then select M3 cell (set active cell M3)

How can I do this?

Comment: Do `A1` and `A2` contain **constants** or **formulas** ??

Answer (score 3):

```
if range("A1").value = range("A2").value then
    range("M3").select
end if
```